# Highlight dates/ranges in xdsoft datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using the [xdsoft datetimepicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker). The readme on github show, that a feature for highlighting time periods is included:

[image]

So I searched for it in the [documentation](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/), but couldn't find information how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

The plugin documentation does lack updates. However, looking at the source code, it seems like there are two options you can use to highlight periods between two dates or specific dates. These options can be set when calling the script or via the setOptions method, examples below :

```
jQuery('#elem').datetimepicker({
    ...,
    highlightedPeriods: [
        "dateStartP1, dateEndP1, 'Description P1', css-class-p1",
        "dateStartP2, dateEndP2, 'Description P2', css-class-p2"
    ],
    ...
    highlightedDates: [
        "date1, 'Description D1', css-class-d1",
        "date2, 'Description D2', css-class-d2",
    ],
    ...
    onShow: function(date, inst) {
        this.setOptions({
            highlightedDates: ["date3, 'Description D3', css-class-d3"]
        })
    }
    ...
});
```

> `highlightPeriods` is an array of strings composed of **4** parameters separated by a comma : 
> **"start date, end date, description, CSS class"**
>   `highlightDates` is an array of strings composed of **3** parameters separated by a comma : 
> **"date, description, CSS class"**
>   The last two parameters are optional and if you don't specify them, no tooltip will be added and a default class `xdsoft_highlighted_default` will be set.

---

**Example - Highlighting dates between April 10 and April 20 :**

```
highlightedPeriods: ["2017/04/10, 2017/04/20, 'My description', my-highlight-style"]
```

This will highlight every date between April 10 and April 20, set a tooltip when hovering any of these dates with the text `My description` and add a css class `my-highlight-style` to each of them.

**Example - Highlighting April 1 :**

```
highlightedDates: ["2017/04/01, 'April Fools', my-highlight-style"]
```

This will highlight  April 1, set a tooltip when hovering any of these dates with the text `April Fools` and add a css class `my-highlight-style` to it.

---

You can then style the highlighted dates as you wish using the css
   class you specified 
(here : `my-highlight-style`).

Plus, if you need to dynamically retrieve the dates, you can use jQuery :
`highlightedDates: [jQuery("#myInput").val() + ", 'User entered date', my-highlight-style"]`

> Please note that the dates must be in the **same format** as your datetimepicker options :
>   `format: 'Y/m/d',`
>   `formatDate: 'Y/m/d'`

Late answer but hopefully it will still help !

Comment: Thank you Thomas... it helped a lot... +1